# Counting rows based on the date it has and the current end of the week

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

**Problem to solve**:
Given 2 rows, containing the author's name and a date, you have to count how many rows that author has.
The tricky part here is that I have to use the date row and check how many entries does that author have within the week of that date he entered.

**What my data looks like:**

[image]

**Expected output**:
[image]

Let's hypothetically say that today is the 19th of February and it's a Friday.
I need to count each row that has a date between 15th of February (Monday) and 21st of February (Sunday).

Next week, from 22nd of February, I need to start it over and check it again for that week and so on.

So, I'm trying to better understand how to approach a simple / stupid problem that I can't find a solution to it.
I've been messing around with the QUERY() function but with no luck since I have literally no idea what lead to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT

*(based on OP's [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/151096/counting-rows-based-on-the-date-it-has-and-the-current-end-of-the-week#comment137759_151097))*

> *... I need to count them only if they are part of the same week.*

Use the following formula

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({A1:A, B1:B, WEEKNUM(B1:B,2)}), 
             "select Col1, count(Col3)
              where Col1 is not null 
                and Col3="&WEEKNUM(TODAY(),2)&"
              group by Col1, Col2
              label count(Col3) 'in this week' ", 1)
```

[image]

The trick here is the creation of a virtual array holding the week-number.

If you want to just group them based on weeks, just omit the `and` clause `and Col3="&WEEKNUM(TODAY(),2)&"`

*(Do not forget to adjust for your locale. If still in trouble please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.)*

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Please use the following [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) formula

```
=QUERY(A1:B,"select A, count(B) 
               where A<>'' 
                  and B <= DATE '"&TEXT(TODAY(),   "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
                  and B >= DATE '"&TEXT(TODAY()-7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
               group by A",1)
```

[image]

*(I believe your image of shown expected result is wrong since it just counts all values and is not based on the dates within the current week)*

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`WEEKNUM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294949)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: After some more digging, trial and error, the following query that should produce something doesn't output anything and I have no idea why even tho it seems correct:
```=QUERY(A$1:B; "SELECT A, COUNT(B) WHERE B >= date '2021-02-15' AND B <= date '2021-02-21' GROUP BY A ORDER BY A ASC"; 1)```

Comment: Please see the updated answer. As for *"I wasted a lot of time since I..."*, if you just copy and paste the formula from the answer, Google is smart enough to change it to your locale.

Comment: Wonderful, it works!
Any way to make it also work with dates that have "dd-mm-yyyy" format?

Comment: *"Any way to make it also work with dates that have "dd-mm-yyyy" format?"* Have you tried it? If not do so and if still having issues please share a test sheet.

Comment: Yup, already tried and I can confirm that it only works if I input the date exactly as "mm-dd-yyyy" even if I set the column to have a different date format.
Here's a like where you can see it on my test sheet (the green cells are those counted and formatted like "mm-dd-yyyy"): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dvsXeNRPKIHTULTdEyhBErplpD_svNYKBck6em4kt2c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This happens because not all your cells are dates (according to your locale). You can [see that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crzod.png) using the `ISDATE` function. Those cells need to be corrected. Since this is a common  mistake (and entirely different from your original question,) you could probably turn it to a new question *(like: How to fix array of dates with mixed locale)* so I can properly answer it. Not many readers make it this far down to the comments. Do let me know of your decision.

Comment: There's no need, I change the locale from `United States` to `Italy` and now everything is working as intended.
Thanks again!